# How do I get two databases to display on two radio buttons selection one for each button

Tags: php, mysql

I have two databases for local state and another one for country and i have two radio buttons for same as mentioned above.What should i do so that if i select local state it display only that database and if another it displays the other one.
This is just a testing code,will connect the database later.

```
enter code here
<html>
<?php include 'header.php';?>
<body>
<div class="radio-buttons">
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radios" value="all" >
<label for="radio1">Domestic</label>
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radios"value="false">
<label for="radio2">International</label>
</div>
<?php
$radio1 = "" ;
$radio2= "" ;
if($radio1=='checked'){
echo "correct";
}
else if($radio2=='checked'){
echo "awsome";
}
?>
```

Comment: First of all you need some code.

Comment: Now what is the problem?Please complete your question.

Comment: Are you asking what to do when 'domestic' is selected and you want to process two different databases? i.e. are we talking about the actual database processing? OR are we talking about displaying radio buttons on the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like below.

```
<?php
$radio = "" ;
if(isset($_GET["db"]))
{ 
    $radio = $_GET["db"];
}

if($radio == 'domestic'){
    echo 'domestic';
} else {
    echo 'awsome';
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function autoSubmit()
{
    var formObject = document.forms['dbForm'];
    formObject.submit();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name='dbForm' id='dbForm'>
    <input type="radio" name="db" <?php if ($radio == 'domestic') { ?>checked='checked' <?php } ?> value="domestic" onChange="autoSubmit();" />Domestic
    <input type="radio" name="db" <?php if ($radio == 'international') { ?>checked='checked' <?php } ?> value="international" onChange="autoSubmit();" /> International    
</form>
</body>
</html>
```